# Is there a way to see only the applications running in a specific workspace?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I rarely have use for wokrspaces, but when I do, it is because I have lots of windows open and want to divide them to different desktops (workspaces) for clarity. However the sidebar shows all the opened windows in every workspace, and alt-tab also has every window from every workspace. Is there a way to easily see only the windows open in one workspace, so that I could move between the windows of that workspace? As it is the whole workspace system seems entirely pointless (since I mostly have maximized windows for text editing and such), so I must be missing something here.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There will be some changes coming up related to this, some interesting reading
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/863399

Atm, other than expo (super+s), you can do a spread on windows in the **current WS** using Shift+Alt+up arrow

The spread (scale) can be enhanced to some degree by enabling the Scale Addons & Text plugins which will provide an window tilebar overlay with various options

Comment: Thank you! The Shift+Alt+up arrow was exactly what I was looking for.